# X axis should have a space in Line chart- Chart JS

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I was trying to create a line chart and it is working as expected, except for one small design improvement.

The line chart created starts by touching the first point from the Y-axis but I would like it to have a bit of a space before it.

Chart I am generating:

[image]

Chart I want to generate:

[image]

I was unable to find the exact keyword to search it up within the documents.
Here attached is the code I have been working with:
[Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-yq2xrd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `xAxes.offset: true` and it should work as expected.

```
xAxes: [
    {
      offset: true,
      ... 
    }
  ]
```

> [`offset`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/#common-configuration): If `true`, extra space is added to both edges and the axis is scaled to fit into the chart area.

Please take a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-ca28qn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).